# UFW port open but connection still refused

Tags: firewall, port, ufw

I have mongodb running and I want to access it from an external machine

Output from ufw status

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere
27017                      ALLOW       Anywhere
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
27017 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

output from telnet  27017

```
Connecting To <ip>...Could not open connection to the host, on port 27017: Connect failed
```

output from netstat -tulpn

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:433             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

sudo systemctl status mongod

```
 * mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-01-15 07:20:51 CET; 51min ago
  Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
```

I have tried reinstalling mongo, restarting ufw etc...What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I guess ufw is not problem, but netstat shows 127.0.0.1:27017, which is incorrect if you want to access port 27017 from externally. You have to change your MongoDB configuration from `bindIp: 127.0.0.1` to `bindIp: 0.0.0.0` and restart mongod.service.

Comment: @jinyus please don't comment to say  *"thank you"* but [vote up and accept the answer](https://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers) to indicate that is correct and/or helped you resolve your problem.

Comment: in a python server you set the actual server host ip address instead of 0.0.0.0